# how to save an excel workbook with multiple worksheets into multiple corresponding csv files in excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

i have an excel workbook which has got some 125 worksheets and i need to be able to save each of those 125 worksheets into csv files(so that i end up with a total of 125 csv files)

am currently able to do this manually(file>save as>csv file type) but only in such a manner:
1st worksheet-->1st csv
2nd worksheet-->2nd csv
.
.
and so on

is there a way to save the entire workbook at once- as opposed to saving just the currently active sheet,then moving on to the next one....?

Comment: Would you consider a python-based option? Are the files `.xls` or `.xlsx`

Comment: the excel workbook is in .xlsx format......what abt python? creating an automated program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Use VBA Macro to Save each Excel Worksheet as Separate Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940604/3536342) by Sorceri:

Keeping the worksheet in the existing workbook and creating a new workbook with a copy

```
Dim path As String
Dim dt As String
dt = Now()
path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\Calendars " & Replace(Replace(dt, ":", "."), "/", ".")
MkDir path
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & path, vbNormalFocus)

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'SetVersions
    If ws.Name <> "How-To" And ws.Name <> "Actg_Prd" Then
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ws.Application.Workbooks.Add
        ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.SaveAs path & ws.Name, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Set wb = Nothing
    End If
Next ws
```

Another solution can by found at [Create a workbook from every worksheet in your workbook](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win007.htm):

> This macro will copy every visible worksheet in a new workbook and save the workbook with the name of
>   the sheet in a newly created folder in the same path as the workbook with this macro.

Comment: thnks davidpostill....i tried the first of the 2 macros and it worked flawlessly. it took in one workbook with abt 125 sheets and spit out 125 seperate workbooks. but still, how do i go about saving each one of them as csv

Comment: i created a macro(not excel macro) which uses previously recorded keyboard and mouse input along with various other environment variables, using a software called jitbit macro recorder and hence solved this problem :) but its mostly luckware coz things can go awry even if theres a very minor change in environment....................it was nice if the excel macros posted above also saved those excel documents

Comment: the excel macro by david is perfect. however a few more lines of code to the macro can give it the ability to also save the files that it generates so am marking it as the best one

Comment: or maybe the macro also saves(wb.SaveAs path & ws.Name, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook) but i dont know where to

Comment: update: the 2nd excel macro by david did the job for me with 100% accuracy

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the script on [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2972-excel-save-export-convert-multiple-all-sheets-to-csv-text.html) but had issues with the Copy command failing and I'm not sure why. So I made a simplified version of the script which does the job nicely for me. It creates a CSV file for each worksheet in the workbook, named the same as the workbook, but with the worksheet name appended.

To run the script, press Alt + F11 to bring up the Visual Basic tool and then choose Insert - Module. Copy and paste the script below and press F5 to run it. This should result in what you were looking for in the original question.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim originalFileName As String
    originalFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        xWs.Activate
        xcsvFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & originalFileName & "_" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
End Sub
```